# If $A$ is normal and $A = PU$ then $PU = UP$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A ∈ M_n$, and $A$ is normal and $A = PU$ be a polar decomposition($U$ is unitary matrix and $P$ is positive semidefinite matrix) .

Is this true that $PU = UP$?

Comment: What do *you* think? Some context would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

We can assume that $P$ and $U$ are invertable, since otherwise we can write $A=A'\oplus 0$ in some basis, and compute the polar resolution there. We have that, by Normality of $A$, $PU(PU)^*=PUU^*P^*=P^2$ coincides with $(PU)^*PU=U^*P^2U$, so since $U^*=U^{-1}$, $P^2U=UP^2$. Now $U$ is diagonlizable, as is $A$, so that $P$ is diagnoliazable, so that $P^2$ is. Thus we have that $U$ and $P^2$ admit simultaneous diagnolization. We can show that $P$ is diagonalized in this basis. Take $P^2v=\lambda^2v$, then $(P+\lambda)(P-\lambda)v=0$. So $(P-\lambda)v$ is a $-\lambda$ eigenvector, so by nonegativity of eigenvalues, $(P-\lambda)v=0$. Thus $P$ is diagonal, and so $P$ and $U$ commute.

Comment: Please more guide.